# how to filter array and slice results with jq

Tags: json, select, slice, jq

Suppose I have the following data:

```
{
   "dashboards": [
     {
       "name": "first",
       "type": "standard"
     },
     {
       "name": "second",
       "type": "custom"
     }
   ]
}
```

(actually there's a lot more data than that, I am just showing what the structure of the data is)

What I am trying to do is get the first 10 dashboards of type `standard`.

I know I can get *all* the `standard` dashboards with:
`jq '.dashboards[] | select(.type == "standard")'`

But I can't figure out how to slice the resulting array...

Comment: jq can't parse your sample because keys aren't disclosed in double quotes

Comment: fixed (was using JavaScript JSON notation...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the result as an array, you could use `map`:

```
.dashboards | map(select(.type=="standard")) | .[0:10]
```

However, this is inefficient. For efficiency, it would be better to use `limit` as discussed below.

If you wanted the items as a stream, you could write:

```
limit(10; .dashboards[] | select(.type=="standard"))
```

If you want the results as an array, simply wrap the above jq expression in square brackets.